# select specific properties from People Manager with rest api

Tags: rest, people-search, search-query

i use this query to get User properties

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=%27SP%5Catish%27
```

In response i get a `UserProfileProperties` object which shows all the information in key value format.

I do not want all these properties. Is it possible to select specific properties from this `UserProfileProperties` object?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use it like this for single property:

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|gautam@rapidcircle.onmicrosoft.com'
```

for multiple properties use it like this:

```
var theData = {
 "propertiesForUser": {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser" }, 
    "accountName": "i:0#.f|membership|gautam@rapidcircle.onmicrosoft.com",
    "propertyNames": ["PreferredName", "Department"]
     }
};

var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};

jQuery.ajax({
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertiesFor",
    type:"POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        console.log(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: try it..but It shows `The parameter name propertyName is not valid.` error

Comment: is it Office 365 or OnPrem ?

Comment: it is OnPrem...

Comment: /_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='domain\username' - try like this.
Also make sure , you are entering correct property name.

Comment: this also shows same error

Comment: Are you certain that you are requesting the right property name? You have to request the internal name, not the display name.